# How do I use a method that has SearchContext , By as arguments in webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, pageobjects

I am having a page object framework for selenium webdriver. This wrapper class below has below methods. I am trying to understand the code. It would be nice if someone can explain waitElementIsVisible method and how to use it.
How do I use the waitElementVisible method or how do I call it in my page object design.

```
public  class WebDriverWrapper {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebDriverWrapper.class);

    /**
     * Default value of the wait timeout as obtained from configuration.
     */
    public static final long IMPLICITLY_WAIT_TIMEOUT = EnvironmentProperties.IMPLICITLY_WAIT_TIMEOUT;
    private static final long INTERVAL_SECONDS = 1;

    private WebDriver driver;

    public WebDriverWrapper(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }


public boolean waitElementIsVisible(SearchContext context, By by, long timeoutSeconds) {
        boolean visible = false;
        setTimeout(0);
        FluentWait<SearchContext> wait = new FluentWait<SearchContext>(context).withTimeout(timeoutSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS).ignoring(NotFoundException.class);
        try {
            visible = wait.until(elementVisible(by));
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            visible = false;
        } finally {
            setTimeout();
        }
        return visible;
}


   private static Function<SearchContext, Boolean> elementVisible(final By by) {
        return new Function<SearchContext, Boolean>() {
            public Boolean apply(@NotNull SearchContext context) {
                return context != null ? context.findElement(by).isDisplayed() : false;
            }
        };
    }
}
=================

How do i use the waitElementVisible method or how do i call in my page object design

public class CAPage extends WebDriverWrapper {
    protected static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CheckoutLoginPage.class);
    protected static final int SETUP_TIMEOUT = 600000;

    protected CAPage caPage;
    public String URL;

    public CAPage(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    private static final String LOGIN="loginButton";

@FindBy(id = LOGIN )
    private WebElement loginBUttonWebelement;

public boolean logInButtonElementPresent(){

        return waitElementIsVisible(what should i put here?);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
waitElementIsVisible(driver, By.id, 5)
```

SearchContext is an interface that defines whether you want to search for your element in the whole page(use driver object) or within a containing element(use webelement object).

Read more here - https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/index.html?org/openqa/selenium/SearchContext.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The example that you have given 
waitElementIsVisible(driver, By.id, 5) as per my understanding uses search context as webdriver. Is it possible to use WebElement context here. could you that code.

Comment: @Indu Instead of driver instance pass in the WebElement instance that contains the login button...

Comment: waitElementIsVisible(loginBUttonWebelement, By.id, 5) will be right? Here loginBuuttonWebelement and By.id are actually pointing at the same webElement. So searching in the context of loginBUttonWebelement would mean what? Could you please explain. Is this a good example for search context with WebElement. or could you provide a better example.

Comment: If you have an html like this <div id='container'><p id='entry'>Hello</p></div>... To get the p using your code you need to pass the div webelement to the method.